# Am I being too strict when not accepting answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, specific-question

As a relative newbie who's only gotten active recently, I now have three questions for which I've received one or more answers, none of which I've accepted because I don't think they answered the question. Am I being too strict? Am I asking stupid or impossible or otherwise flawed questions? I am eager to be a good Stack Overflow citizen, and want to do the right thing.

On one hand, I'm worried that I'm being too strict about not accepting certain answers -- meaning other users aren't getting recognition they deserve and also leading to my accept rate being noticeably low and likely causing folks to not want to answer my questions in the future. (Note that I do upvote answers that are partially helpful even if not accepted.)

On the other hand, I want to be responsible in accepting answers -- and avoid accepting something "just because" -- since I know these questions and answers will be seen by others in the future.

For reference, here are my questions:

1. [Tips for configuring PyDev/Eclipse for optimal Django template editing (sans Aptana)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263240/tips-for-configuring-pydev-eclipse-for-optimal-django-template-editing-sans-apt) (I specifically asked for non-Aptana tips, and the only answer I got was to use Aptana.)
2. [In Sublime Text 2, how to select beginning and end of selected block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563725/in-sublime-text-2-how-to-select-beginning-and-end-of-selected-block) (One answer came close in saying the feature I was asking about "seems" to have been removed from Sublime Text 2, but without certainty. I tried to get certainty in discussion via comments, but didn't. If I had, I would have accepted the answer.)
3. [In Django, how can I order by a multiple-choice CharField in arbitrary not alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695994/in-django-how-can-i-order-by-a-multiple-choice-charfield-in-arbitrary-not-alpha) (Several people gave perfectly valid answers which solve the example I gave in straightforward ways, but didn't get at the heart of what I was trying to do. I ended up figuring out what I wanted myself and answering it myself. Unless something else comes up, I will, I suppose, accept my own answer tomorrow when I'm allowed to. Perhaps my question was too literal or not specific enough about what I was looking for?)

So again: am I being too strict in not accepting? Are my questions flawed in some way? Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: No, you're not being too strict. It's just three difficult questions, don't worry :)

Comment: @minitech - thanks. Follow-up question: should I be worried that a relatively low accept rate will make folks less likely to answer my questions?

Comment: Don't worry about accept rate, you ask excellent questions that people *want* to find answers to. In any case, Jeff Atwood stated that a 70% accept rate is awesome, your 67% in not far off from that.